# SELECT Query from Two tables with GroupBy Function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am working Oracle APEX, i am little bit confused in Queries how to make it. I created two tables with following attributes

```
Employees(  "EMP_ID", 
    "EMP_NAME", 
    "EMP_DESIGNATION" , 
    "EMP_ADDRESS" , 
    "EMP_GENDER", 
    "EMP_CONTACT", 
    "EMP_EMAIL" , 
    "EMP_JOINING_DATE", 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_EMP_ID" PRIMARY KEY ("EMP_ID") ENABLE
   );`
```

and

```
Attendance
(   ATT_ID, 
    EMP_ID, 
    ATT_STATUS, 
    ATT_IN DATE, 
    ATT_OUT DATE, 
    ATT_COMMENTS, 
CONSTRAINT "PK_ATT_ID" PRIMARY KEY ("ATT_ID") ENABLE
CONSTRAINT "FK_EMP_ID" FOREIGN KEY ("EMP_ID") REFERENCES "EMPLOYEES" ("EMP_ID"));
```

I  have subtracted the `Att_Out` from `Att_In` to get the Time in MINUTES which i get and then `multiply` it with `.69` which is the salary of employees per minute as shown in diagram with Query.

```
select emp_id,sum(((att_out-att_in)*1440)*.69) as "minutes*sal/m" 
from attendance group by emp_id;
```

[image]

I want to `select EMP_ID,EMP_NAME` from `Employees` Table with the rest of the query as mentioned above. I did with `INNER JOIN` but then `group by` function is giving me error.

Comment: If it does not work still, try adding order by in the end for fields you are trying to select as columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT e.emplid, e.emp_name,  
sum(((a.att_out-a.att_in)*1440)*.69) as "minutes*sal/m"
FROM Employees e 
inner join attendance a on e.emplid = a.emplid
group by e.emplid, e.emp_name
```

Comment: @MuhammadUsman, what are you talking about? Did you try to execute this? Did this throw any error?  if you are talking about att_out, att_in then you dont need alias because they are only in attendance table.

Comment: This query will work, unless you have att_out, att_in in employee table. What error do you get when you run this query?

Comment: Please Check the tables above Att_in,att_out are in Attendance Table

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
select emp_id,sum(((att_out-att_in)*1440)*.69) as "minutes*sal/m" from attendance a,employees e 
where e.emp_id=a.emp_id
group by emp_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.emp_id, e.emp_name, sum(((a.att_out-a.att_in)*1440)*.69) as "minutes*sal/m" 
FROM Employees e 
inner join attendance a on e.emp_id = a.emp_id 
group by e.emp_id, e.emp_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be helpful for you:

```
SELECT e.emplid, e.emp_name,  
sum(((a.att_out-a.att_in)*1440)*.69) as  employees_salary_per_minute
FROM Employees e 
inner join attendance a on e.emplid = a.emplid
group by e.emplid, e.emp_name
```